# Samsung Android BLE multiple read/write

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, characteristics

In Samsung 4.2 to 4.3 BLE App Migration Guide (http://developer.samsung.com/ble) it says:

> The synchronous nature of the stack and F/W hasn’t been affected. That
>   is, if we call for  example, **writeCharacteristic** for a particular
>   characteristic, if it returns true, the next call  to any
>   BluetoothGatt or BluetoothGattServer method should be done after the 
>   **onCharacteristicRead** callback is received. This is because the stack is designed to support and process only one GATT call at a
>   time, and if, for example, you call  writeCharacteristic or
>   readCharacteristic of any characteristic soon after the first one, it 
>   is ignored.

Is there mistake in this paragraph? When I need multiple writes why should I need to read that characteristics  before/after each write? I think it should be like this:

> .. That is, if we call for  example, **writeCharacteristic** for a
>   particular characteristic, if it returns true, the next call  to any
>   BluetoothGatt or BluetoothGattServer method should be done after the 
>   **onCharacteristicWrite** callback is received. ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is of course the onCharacteristicWrite callback. Most likely a copy paste error

Comment: Yes, at first I was reading and then writing. Now it works without reading also.